# Playing with multi "div" sound playter with Soundmanager2

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

Hi ive got this function :

```
function InlinePlayer(){
    $(".playerMedia").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){

        soundManager.stopAll();

       if(!$(this).hasClass("sm2_playing")){ 

        soundManager.createSound({
        id: $(this).attr("data-id"),
        url: $(this).attr("data-url")
    }).play();  $(this).toggleClass("sm2_playing");
       } 
       else {   $(this).toggleClass("sm2_playing");}


        return false;
    });
    }); 
}

soundManager.setup({
  debugMode: false,
  preferFlash: false,
  useFlashBlock: true,
  url: '../../../../sm2/swf/',

  flashVersion: 9
});

InlinePlayer();
```

and ive got some div to play sound :

```
<div class="playerMedia" data-url="http://www.mupiz.com/mp3/5738/mp3_51550.mp3" data-id="la-douleur-chanson-sur-mon-tableau">La Douleur (chanson sur mon tableau)</div>

<div class="playerMedia" data-url="ANOTHER data-id="ANOTHER">La Douleur (chanson sur mon tableau)</div>
```

When i click to one div to play the sound the .sm2_playing is not added and the sound is not played...

Ive got few .playerMedia div which is all individual player onclick the sound is played, if the user click again this sound is stopped.. And every player have to work on their own..

Any ideas ?

Comment: No ideas to make this work ?